# Python3 Casting

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, int

In this code, casting from `float` to `int` is not working.  It always prints a `float`; all integers are printed with `.0` afterwards.
What is wrong?

```
s = str(input())

if (len(s)/2)%2 == 0:
    print(len(s)/2)
else:
    print(int(round(len(s)/2/2)))
```

Comment: What is this code trying to do?

Comment: No repro. If I input 1 I get 0 as output, which is clearly an int and not a float.

Comment: accepting a string as an input and make two tests on its length, and in each case we will have an output but it must be an integer

Comment: What does "two tests" mean

Comment: try to enter this string "abcdcdab" the out put will be 4.0

Comment: You only convert the result to an int in the `else` branch. If your code enters the `if` branch, it outputs a float.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: What is the point of `str(input())`? `input()` returns already a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing you need to change in your code is :-

```
if (len(s)/2)%2 == 0:
    print(int(len(s)/2))
```

this should do the trick
you only converted the result in else block to integer but not in if block

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a little debugging: put in some simple test cases, and print out plenty of results.

```
test = ["odd len", "even len"]

for s in test:
    print("test case", s, len(s), len(s)/2)
    if (len(s)/2)%2 == 0:
        print("EVEN", len(s)/2)
    else:
        print("ODD ", int(round(len(s)/2/2)))
```

Output:

```
test case odd len 7 3.5
ODD  2
test case even len 8 4.0
EVEN 4.0
```

Do you expect the division in your "true" branch to provide an integer?  That's *float* division in Python 3.  I think you want the lines

```
if (len(s)/2)%2 == 0:
    print("EVEN", len(s)//2)
```

which will give you output

```
test case odd len 7 3.5
ODD  2
test case even len 8 4.0
EVEN 4
```

You can save some extra operations by doing the length division only once at the top:

```
half_len = len(s) // 2
```